# Kerastuner ValueError: Shapes (320,) and (1,) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm new to deep learning and tried to tune hyperparameters using kerastuner. Here is my code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch

from kerastuner import HyperModel


class MyHyperModel(HyperModel):

    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        self.input_shape = input_shape

    def build(self, hp):
        model = keras.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units',
                                        min_value=10,
                                        max_value=120,
                                        step=10),
                           activation='relu',
                           input_shape=self.input_shape))
     
     
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units',min_value=10,max_value=20,step=2),
                            activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(
            optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                      values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])),
        loss='mse',
        metrics=['mse'])
        return model

input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],)
hypermodel = MyHyperModel(input_shape)

tuner = RandomSearch(
    hypermodel,
    objective='mse',
    max_trials=10,
    )

tuner.search(X_train, y_train,
         epochs=50,
         validation_data=(X_test, y_test),verbose=0)
```

When I tried to retrieve the best model using

```
tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
```

I got the following error

```
ValueError: Shapes (320,) and (1,) are incompatible
```

I don't have this error when I deleted this hidden layer

```
model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units',min_value=10,max_value=20,step=2),
                            activation='relu'))
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the shape of all your data?

Comment: X_train has shape (4871,14).

Comment: What about y_train?

Comment: y_train is (4871,)

Comment: I ran your code using some random data and I didn't run into any issues. Perhaps it has something to do with your test data. In fact, could you provide the shapes for that as well?

Comment: X_test is (1624,14), y_test is (1624,).